# After removing OverlayItem tap events still trigger

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I have a simple overlay for a Google Map: http://pastebin.com/Rg8miMSh and I add/remove items on it depending on the zoom level. After removing/adding I call populate on the overlay and invalidate on the map view. Everything works just fine, except 1 glitch: after an item was removed, if I tap its location onTap is still triggered and because the OverlayItem is not there anymore i get *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* in *com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.maskHelper(ItemizedOverlay.java:562*) (full stack trace - http://pastebin.com/KThn4ZLE )

Anyone knows why this is happening? Initially i called clear and added all items all over again which didn't seems to cause this problem. However having many items this was becoming a performance issue. Adding/removing only the difference works much faster and I would like to keep this method.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by calling "setLastFocusedIndex(-1);" in "doPopulate()".

Comment: Thanks for following up on your own question!  Just ran into this - thanks for the fix. The android class must hold onto an instance of the now deleted overlayitem causing it to throw on a draw().

Comment: More details of this issue: [ItemizedOverlay & ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException > explanation AND solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/OLETFONHFMM[1-25])

Comment: +1 for great answer i spent more then 3 week to resolve this issue but not successful ...by adding this line i solved my issue thanks for great answer